# Symbolicate crash logs for Parse.com Analytics

Tags: swift, parse-platform, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I'm trying to get crash reporting up and running with parse.com.
The crashes are sent in to Parse Analytics, but I don't think they are symbolicated. I have followed the steps to upload the symbol-files in a runscript on each build.
The crashes I get looks like this:

_TFFFFC8myApp18MainViewController13viewDidAppearFS0_FSbT_U_FT_T_U0_FTGSQGVSs10DictionarySSPSs9AnyObject___GSQCSo7NSError__T_U_FTGSQGS1_SSSS__GSQSb__T_ @ 0x780

Is there a way to check If they are symbolcated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is symbolicated.Usually symbolicated shows you
- App name
- Class name
- Function name
- Function args

> _TFFFFC8myApp18MainViewController13viewDidAppearFS0_FSbT_U_FT_T_U0_FTGSQGVSs10DictionarySSPSs9AnyObject___GSQCSo7NSError__T_U_FTGSQGS1_SSSS__GSQSb__T_
>   @ 0x780

Means
- App name: myApp
- Class name: MainViewController
- Function name: viewDidAppear
- Function args: Dictionary, AnyObject (I'm not sure about this)